# Rails scss l18n

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am translating a rails application with Sass made for LTR languages.
I am translating the app to a RTL language (Hebrew), and I am wondering what's the best practice for organizing my Scss files?

I can create directory for RTL and LTR and put their specific language things like flots and direction.
Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any standard; however, Thoughtbot has a post about a topic like this:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-default/

Maybe you could use similar sturcture for the languages as they did for the clients.